# Is the Vietoris-Rips complex of a point cloud the clique complex of it's neighborhood graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

In [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e503/c24dcc7a8110a001ae653913ccd064c1044b.pdf) they discuss ways of obtaining the Vietoris-Rips complex of a point cloud from it's neighborhood graph. In the neighborhood graph with scale $\epsilon$, two vertices have an edge between them if the distance between them is less than $\epsilon$.

In Section 4.3 they explain that the Vietoris-Rips complex is the clique complex of the neighborhood graph. If I understand correctly, the clique complex is obtained by declaring every complete subgraph to be a simplex. And the Vietoris-Rips complex is obtained by making a simplex out of every set of points that all lie within some ball of diameter $\epsilon$.

If you have three points in the plane, each of which is 1 unit away from the other two, and you select the scale to be 1, the neighborhood graph would be a complete graph on 3 vertices. If the fact about the clique complex is true then the VR complex would be a filled in triangle. But all three points won't fit inside a disc of diameter 1. What am I missing here?

Comment: Where did you see "the Vietoris-Rips complex is obtained by making a simplex out of every set of points that all lie within some ball of diameter $\epsilon$"? Of course, this is also a valid definition but inconsistent with the other one.

Comment: I think that's what the wikipedia is saying. Is it wrong or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: It is not wrong, just it is inconsistent. The two definitions are off by a certain factor.

Comment: A certain factor? It says that any finite subset with diameter less than $\delta$ is made into a simplex. It makes sense that if a certain subset $S$ has a small diameter then all $s\subset S$ should be made faces of $S$ in the simplicial complex. In space, the diameter of a finite set of points would be diameter of the smallest ball that includes all of them right? If points in space have a diameter $<\epsilon$, than there will exist some ball of diameter $\epsilon$ that includes all the points. What is it that's different between the definitions?

Comment: Say, you can use the factor of $4$ (one can do better). The point is that if you have a nonempty subset $A$ in $E^n$ where the distance between any two points is $\le r$, then pick any $a\in A$. Then $A\subset B(a, 2r)$. The diameter of $B(a,2r)$ is $4r$, hence, $diam(A)\le 4r$. This factor ($\le 4$) is the difference between the two definitions.

Comment: If any two points in $A$ have distance $\le r$ then for $a\in A$ all of the farthest points from $a$ should lie on the boundary of a ball with radius $r$ and center $a$, right? Why does your ball have radius $2r$.

Comment: Yes, the radius $r$ will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vietoris-Rips complex of scale $\delta$ is obtained by making a simplex out of every set of points with diameter $\le\delta$. The diameter of a set of points is the least upper bound on the set of distances between the points. The diameter of a finite subset of Euclidean space *does not* correspond to the diameter of the smallest ball that contains all of the points. This is the detail that I glossed over while thinking about this.